# difference between assigning an int and an int literal to a byte ?

Tags: java

```
byte b = 100 ;
```

compiles without any errors, but

```
int i = 100 ; 
byte b = i ;
```

throws an error. Why? Even when assigning 100 directly to b, we are assigning an int literal. So why did I get an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
byte b = 100 ;
```

Here `100` is a compile time constant. And hence can be assigned to the `byte`.

```
int i = 100 ; 
// i = i + 100;  // It's allowed to add this statement later on, 
                 // if `i` is not declared final. And hence, the next assignment
                 // will clearly fail at runtime. So, compiler saves you from it
byte b = i ;
```

Now in this case, since `i` is not declared `final`, so it is no more a `compile time` constant. And in that case, you can later on come and *modify* the value of `i`, in between the `initialization of i`, and `assignment of i to byte`, as in the above case. Which will certainly fail.
That is why compiler does not allow the assignment of `i` to `byte` type.

But, you can use an explicit casting for it to compile, which may of course `crash` at runtime. By doing an explicit cast, you tell the compiler that - "I know what I'm doing, just do it for me". So, it will not bother about runtime behaviour of that casting, and will trust you that you are not doing anything wrong.

So, either you can declare your `int i` as `final`, or you need to do the casting: -

```
int i = 100 ;    // replace 100 with 130, and you will be surprised that it works
byte b = (byte)i ;
```

So, when you use a value `130` and cast it to `byte`, you pass through the `compiler`, but will certainly crash at runtime. And this is the problem that the `compiler` was trying to avoid.

---

Now let's go back the first case: -

```
byte b = 128;
```

The above assignment will now fail to compile. Because even though the value `128` is a compile time constant, it is not big enough to fit in a `byte`, and that the `compiler` knows.

Answer (score 1):

`byte b=100` would compile because byte's range is from **-128 to 127**.

```
    int i = 100 ; byte b = 129 ;// would give a compiler error
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, which is _why will the 2nd version not compile?_

Comment: @jlordo `Even when assigning 100 directly to b, we are assigning an int literal` is in the question. it does answer one part of the question and certainly is important to understand. just because, i dint answer the first part doesnt mean you could downvote me :P

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not final and could have changed in the mean time.

Following would work:

```
final int i = 100; 
byte b = i;
```